# Non-existence of distance minimizers for non-convex closed subsets of Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $K$ be a non-empty closed subset of $H$. Fix a point $x\in H$. If $K$ is convex, the [Hilbert projection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_projection_theorem) gives us a unique distance minimizer $y\in K$, in the sense that $\|y-x\|\le\|y'-x\|$ for all $y'\in K$. If we do not need uniqueness, we can replace the convexity assumption with compactness. In particular, if $H=\mathbf R^d$, any closed $K$ will have a distance minimizer (since if we set $D:=\inf_{y'\in K}\|y'-x\|<\infty$, we may consider the compact set $\overline{B(x,D+1)}\cap K$).

I am interested in situations where no distance minimizer exists. For example, if $H=\mathbf R$, $K=(0,1)$, and $x=0$, so that $K$ is convex but not closed, then no distance minimizer exists, as all points of $K$ are at a positive distance away from $x$, whereas $\inf_{y'\in(0,1)}\|y'-x\|=0$.

How do I construct a non-convex closed subset $K$ of a Hilbert space $H$ for which no distance minimizer exists? As discussed earlier, $H$ cannot be $\mathbf R^d$ or $\mathbf C^d$. I tried working with $\ell^2(\mathbf Z)$ but did not get far. (I would prefer just a hint, rather than a full solution.)

Thank you.

Comment: A natural candidate would be the unit sphere of an infinite-dimensional Hilbert. Except of course that it’s too regular too work. So how about deforming it a little?

Comment: @Mindlack Doesn't the minimizer exist for the unit sphere?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: yes, indeed, because this sphere is very regular and well-behaved – that’s why I suggested to deform it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take
$$ K = \{ (1+1/n) e_n \mid n \in \mathbb N\},$$
where $e_n$ are the canonical unit sequences. Then, $K$ is closed, the distance of $0$ to $K$ is $1$, but this distance is not attained.

Comment: In fact, the problem is mainly linked with the non-compactness of $K$ more than its non-convexity no ? For instance if you take in the Hilbert space $\mathbb{R}$, the set $K=\{0\}\cup\{2\}$ is not convex but compact and the distance of $1$ to $K$ is attained by every points of $K$ ! I guess to break existence you have to find a non compact set right !?

Comment: I would say both, since a minimizer exists if (a) $K$ is closed and convex, or (b) $K$ is compact.

Comment: I guess (a) works if $K$ is included in a Hilbert space (it is the case here) otherwise it could be different, for instance if it was included in a Banach space or a normed vector space !

Comment: Yes. More generally, (a) works if the surrounding space is a reflexive Banach space (by using weak convergence).